# What is the difference between `Host` and `URL.Host` for golang `http.Request`?

Tags: http, go

When developing golang http application, I use `http.Request` a lot. When accessing request host address, I would use `req.Host`, but I find that there is `req.URL.Host` field, but when I print it, it's empty.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("uri Host: " + r.URL.Host + " Scheme: " + r.URL.Scheme)
    fmt.Println("Host: " + r.Host)
}
```

The documentation of [http.Request](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go) gives the following comments, while `net/url` does not give much clue.

```
// For server requests Host specifies the host on which the
// URL is sought. Per RFC 2616, this is either the value of
// the "Host" header or the host name given in the URL itself.
// It may be of the form "host:port". For international domain
// names, Host may be in Punycode or Unicode form. Use
// golang.org/x/net/idna to convert it to either format if
// needed.
//
// For client requests Host optionally overrides the Host
// header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses
// the value of URL.Host. Host may contain an international
// domain name.
Host string
```

It seems to me that there are two host value in a request: uri line and `Host` header, like:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

But it does not solve many problems than it creates:

1. Why are there two different `Host` field in request? I mean isn't this a duplicate?
2. Can the two `Host` fields be different in the same request?
3. Which one should I use for what situation?

Answers with a real HTTP request example would be the best. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [`r.URL`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.URL) field is created by parsing the HTTP request URI.

The [`r.Host`](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Host) field is the value of the [Host request header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4). It's the same value as calling `r.Header.Get("Host")`.

If the HTTP request on the wire is:

```
 GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.example.org:8080
```

then `r.URL.Host` is "" and `r.Host` is `www.example.org:8080`.

The value of `r.URL.Host` and `r.Host` are almost always different.  On a proxy server, `r.URL.Host` is the host of the target server and `r.Host` is the host of the proxy server itself. When not connecting through a proxy, the client does not specify a host in the request URI. In this scenario, `r.URL.Host` is the empty string.

If you are not implementing a proxy, then you should use `r.Host` to determine the host.