# golang http allow certain domain name both with www and without

Tags: http, go, cors

I have a golang api I'm writting. I use the following function for cors

```
func ResponseWithJSON(w http.ResponseWriter, json []byte, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    w.Write(json)
}
```

This allows my api to be accessible by anyone. I would like to limit it to my domain name. Because that sounds more secure. Lets call it www.example.com

I can Change it to

```
 w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com")
```

And this will allow me to make calls when the url is www.example.com but not example.com

I can then change it to

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://example.com")
```

Now I can access my api from example.com but not www.example.com

Adding both does not work
Neither this way

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com,http://example.com")
```

Nor This way

```
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://example.com")
```

So, is there a way for me to get the requesting origin? so I can dynamically allow the domain? Is there another way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the request `host` header and serve the response correspondingly.

Comment: How do I do that? Do you have any examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42921567/251311

Comment: FWIW, setting the same header multiple times won’t work with [`Header.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Set) as it replaces any previously set values. Instead use [`Header.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Add).

Comment: No that doesn't work. Now it says

    The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Comment: If you want both try this: `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://www.example.com http://example.com")` - space as separator instead of a comma. According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) the list is space separated.

Comment: Apparently 'Neither comma separated, nor space separated domains did work. Matching against a list of domains and putting a single host in the headers is still better security and does work properly.' So back to @zerkms comments. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309318/best-method-access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: Yeah it still complains about multiple headers. I feel like that would be the ideal sollution. I did finally figure it out this morning. The information I want is in the http.request object earlier in the code. Assuming you have an object  r *http.Request, you can then get the origin like this origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); So I'm just returning an empty object on each api call if it isn't the correct origin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that the Origin information is in the http.Request object. You can get the origin  with

```
origin := r.Header.Get("Origin");
```

Assuming you have a object some where like

```
r *http.Request
```

If the object is coming from example.com it will return example.com, likewise www.example.com. You can then test if it is one of these two values as a way to authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header supports only a single value, so you have to inspect the [Origin request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) and then make a decision based on that:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch origin := r.Header.Get("Origin"); origin {
    case "www.example.com", "example.com":
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
    }
}
```

Do note that this header is automatically set in browser's requests and can be set in request performed by other user agents (like curl).

Comment: It's r.Header.Get("Origin") Not Host

Comment: Those headers serve different purposes. See [RFC7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4) for a description of the Host header.

Comment: I just tested it and Host is returning an empty string, origin is returning what I asked for, the origin...

Comment: Host is the domain to which the request is being sent to so I don't think it should be set back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. "Origin" is the correct one and we can also omit the `http://`.